# Xcode 10: Ambiguous Constraints Error When Adding Simple Constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode10

I'm working in Xcode 10 and am getting some errors when trying to add some pretty simple constraints to my view.

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` that I'm adding a `UIStackView` to. I size the `UIStackView` to fill the cell and set the top, bottom, left, and right constraints to the Safe Area.

I used to be able to do this in Xcode 9 without error, however, it now gives me an error that I need to specify the **X Position or Width and the Y Position or Height**. Even when I let the interface builder add the missing constraints (**Center X and Center Y**) it gives the same error. I feel like this is a bug in Xcode 10, but if there are new iOS 12 requirements for constraints I don't know about I'd appreciate some help with them.

If I ignore the erroneous constraints and run the app the view does not show up properly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

I definitely think this is a bug. Notice in the screenshot below, even though I have subviews in the stack view, the errors do not go away. Also, when I add static padding to the top, left, bottom, and right it does not show properly in the layout, however it does layout properly when I run the app.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that does not resolve the errors.

Comment: I have the same problem with xcode 10

Comment: I've found that it is only an issue with Stackviews where the Axis property is set to Vertical.

Comment: set Stackviews width equal to textviewcollectionviewcell and attributes to fill and equal spacing. It would resolve

Answer (score 12):

This is, indeed, a bug in Xcode 10. To resolve this issue, **embed the stack view in another view**, which has the same constraints as the stack view before:

[image: view structure]

Comment: Same issue with Xcode 11. May be it's expected behaviour and not a bug?